# AIX: how to use egrep to search the maching pattern?

Tags: grep, aix

I'm looking for how to use `egrep` or `grep` to complete my task.

I want to show the last line of each interfaces. I tried to use `grep` and `egrep` with option but the results didn't mach my expectation.

```
#ifconfig -a

en0: flags=1e080863,480<UP,BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT,CHECKSUM_OFFLOAD(ACTIVE),CHAIN>
        inet 10.x.x.x netmask 0xffffff80 broadcast 10.x.x.x
         tcp_sendspace 16384 tcp_recvspace 16384 rfc1323 0
en1: flags=1e080863,480<UP,BROADCAST,NOTRAILERS,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT,CHECKSUM_OFFLOAD(ACTIVE),CHAIN>
        inet 10.x.x.x netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 10.x.x.x
         tcp_sendspace 262144 tcp_recvspace 262144 rfc1323 1
en2: flags=1e080863,480<UP,BROADCAST,10.x.x.xmask 0xffffff80 broadcast 10.x.x.x
         tcp_sendspace 262144 tcp_recvspace 262144 rfc1323 1
lo0: flags=e08084b,c0<UP,BROADCAST,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,GROUPRT,64BIT,LARGESEND,CHAIN>
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 10.x.x.x
        inet6 ::1%1/0
         tcp_sendspace 131072 tcp_recvspace 131072 rfc1323 1
```

Expected Output:

```
en0: tcp_sendspace 16384 tcp_recvspace 16384 rfc1323 0
en1: tcp_sendspace 262144 tcp_recvspace 262144 rfc1323 1
en2: tcp_sendspace 262144 tcp_recvspace 262144 rfc1323 1
lo0: tcp_sendspace 131072 tcp_recvspace 131072 rfc1323 1
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `grep`. Try with awk: `ifconfig -a | awk -v ORS= '/^[^ \t]+:/{if(i++)print"\n";print $1}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^(tcp_sendspace|tcp_recvspace|rfc1323)$/)print" "$i" "$(i+1)}END{print"\n"}'`

Comment: This sed command will work: `sed -nE '/:|tcp_/!d; s/^([^ ]+:) .*/\1/; Ta; h; :a /tcp_/{; H; x; s/\n +/ /; p; };'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated:*** *tested on AIX 7 server and updated commands according to AIX requirements.*

From manual for **grep**:

```
grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern
```

So the tool is to find and print lines matching some patterns.
But your task is not to find and print some lines, but to customize output.

One of possible solutions would be to use **grep** to exclude not needed lines, and after to use **sed** to format the needed part of output into requested way:

```
ifconfig -a |grep -Ev '^[[:space:]]*inet'|sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/:.*\n/: /g;s/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/ /g'
```

Output:

```
en0: tcp_sendspace 16384 tcp_recvspace 16384 rfc1323 0
en1: tcp_sendspace 262144 tcp_recvspace 262144 rfc1323 1
en2: tcp_sendspace 262144 tcp_recvspace 262144 rfc1323 1
lo0: tcp_sendspace 131072 tcp_recvspace 131072 rfc1323 1
```

Also you can use awk instead (as suggested in comments) or another tool or combinations of tools.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
ifconfig -a | awk '
  /^[^[:space:]]/ {iface = $1; next}
  $1 == "tcp_sendspace" {$1 = $1; print iface, $0}'
```